# paypal express checkout digital goods testing in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I used PayPal's Integration Wiz to generate the code (PHP) for the Express Checkout Digital Goods functionality.  I'll admit, I made a few minor changes to it so that it could work with my site... My site is a single page Angular.js app - so I need to pass back parameters to the app, and not go back to a different page (as it is, I'm not keen on leaving the page at all, but I'm not ready to shell out for a business pro account yet.. the PCI compliance is something I don't relish being on the hook for...but maybe one day... certainly not until I know I can get "basic" things working).

I would not expect any of my changes (basically changing the hardcoded URLS to being PHP session vars) to interrupt any of the flow of the Integration Wiz's processing.

However, when I test things in the sanbox, the process stops at the point of redirection to:

```
 https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token={somevariabletokenconent}
```

The token always starts with "EC-" so I'm assuming this is telling me I've been able to successfully start the Express Checkout process.

All I am seeing is a blank page, with Chrome telling me I'm getting:

```
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

AFAICT my sandbox account is set up for EC/DG:

```
 Your payment solution: PayPal Digital Goods (Express Checkout)
```

I HAVE updated my sandbox details in paypalfunctions.php

And other than the changes in checkout.php, I havent messed with any other code from the integration wizard... should this not "just work" ??

Or have I missed something else?

[Edit]

Update a few hours later...

I actually was able to get things to progress end to end.  Once.  But no record of the transaction can be seen on either side of the sandbox accounts.  It did sit thinking for a long time... so I'm not sure what it was doing, but the final redirect was back with a success parameter, so I have to think that something behind the scenes must be having issues...

But now its not working anymore.  Its stopping in the same spot again.

For the life of me, I don't believe I made any code changes to the PP wiz produced code prior to it working, or prior to it not working again.

I have logged into the sandbox to check the transaction as I mentioned. Both accounts are showing nothing.  And the transactions are not processing.

[EDIT 2]

Ok - strange things are afoot.  I know I did absolutely no changes since my last test...I havent even been at the keyboard. And upon trying again, the test proceeds to allow me to log into the sandbox, and approve a payment, but gets stuck processing at

```
  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/checkout/webflow/sparta/expresscheckoutvalidatedataflow?execution=e1s2
```

with the PayPal "Loading" icon spinning...

Is this a configuration issue on my side?  With the Integration Wiz writing all the Express Checkout code, there's not to change, but it seems really flakey to me.

[EDIT3]

I've been hanging my head on this for about a day now, and got nowhere. My App is a single page Angular.js site, and triggers the PayPal purchase out of a Bootstrap Modal popup window.

As mentioned above, my process would get to the point of approving and confirming payment, then spin wildly at the point it should be redirecting back to the success (or failure) page.

Using the PP integration Wiz, the form code that was produced (and used) was:

```
<form name='ppcheckout' action='checkout.php' METHOD='POST'>
```

And it fails to proceed to the final redirect.

However, if I change the code to:

```
<form name='ppcheckout' action='checkout.php' METHOD='POST' target="_blank">
```

The processing occurs as expected.

Is there some interaction between PayPal's JS and Angular (or Bootstrap) that I'm not aware of?  It seems strange that it "just works" when the target is added.

Comment: I think I found the answer.   PayPal processing doesnt like it when you're logged into their systems... not the Sandbox, not the developer site, not the prod system....

I'm still unable to use the "remember me" ... as soon as I do, the behaviour returns - which points me back to cookies from them being involved... but I can get around the above problem.